# Remove a ViewController from navigationStack and add a new instance of it

Tags: swift, navigationcontroller

I have a SongNamesViewController with navigationController embedded.  When a song is chosen from a list I open PlaySongViewController and add to the navigationController using following function:

```
func openPlaySongViewController() {     
  let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let playSongViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "playSongViewController")
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(playSongViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Now, a message arrives via remote push-notification.  The user taps on the push-notification icon and then I display the song using "openPlaySongViewController()" function.  If another push-notification comes and then I display another PlaySongViewController on top of existing PlaySongViewController.

Current flow: `(NavigationController)->SongNamesViewController>PlaySongViewController->PlaySongViewController`

How do I remove the existing PlaySongViewController that is on the navigationController before adding a new instance of PlaySongViewController?

I tried the following but the PlaySongViewController that is on navigationController does not go away.

```
for viewController in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {                
     if viewController.isKind(of: PlaySongViewController.self) {                   
          viewController.removeFromParent()                                 
     }
}
```

Comment: Here `(NavigationController)->SongNamesViewController>PlaySongViewController->PlaySongViewController` you have 2 instances of `PlaySongViewController`  Do you need to remove the 2 or the last 1

Comment: I want to remove the existing PlaySongViewController that is on the navigationController before adding another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`topViewController` returns what is on top of the navigation stack. So you should `pop` it if needed.

```
func removeLastControllerIfNeeded() {
    guard navigationController?.topViewController is PlaySongViewController else { return }
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This does this:  PlaySongViewController->SongNamesViewController->PlaySongViewController. Not sure why it doesn't go SongNamesViewController. It's as if the  code "self.navigationController?.pushViewController(playSongViewController, animated: true)" doesn't add the viewcontroller.